# URL Rewrite www to non-www resulting in redirect loop

Tags: asp.net, url-rewriting

I'm trying to setup a rewrite rule in IIS 7 to redirect users to a non-www url:

```
<rule name="WWW to non-WWW"> 
<match url="(.*)" /> 
<conditions logicalGrouping="MatchAll" trackAllCaptures="false"> 
    <add input="{HTTP_HOST}" pattern="^domain.com$" negate="true" /> 
</conditions> 
<action type="Redirect" url="domain.com/{R:1}" />
```

But I keep getting a redirect loop when visiting `www.domain.com` or just `domain.com`. I can't seem to work out where the problem is, and am even suspecting that is may be something else that is causing the issue? From the way I am reading the rule, `negate="true"` should redirect anything that is doesn't match to the non-www url right?